# Why I am getting an error "Braintree-API.h" file not found

Tags: ios8.1, braintree

Hello friends I am working on an application where i want to integrate Braintree for payment. I followed git hub manual. It say's that you will find an error "Braintree-API.h" and you can fix by make it public. But there is no any option to make it public. How to do it. Please help. I am facing this issue from 5 hours.
following link:  https://github.com/exchangegroup/braintree-framework-builder

[image: This is Braintree.h]

[image: This is Braintree-API.h]

[image: And this is error]

[image]

Comment: Show the full compiler command line (or just all of the `-I` options passed to the compiler) and then show the file structure (i.e. how this library and its header files are stored within your project).

Comment: Droppy,Check my updated question.

Comment: As you can see the `Braintree.h` file is expecting to find the other header files under the sub-directory `Braintree`, so you need to set your *Header Search Path* to include the parent of that `Braintree` sub-directory in order for that to work.

Comment: thanks droppy, can u plz tell how to set Headet Search Path here.

Comment: It's in the *Build Settings* for the target.

Answer (score 2):

I work on Braintree iOS.

In the [Braintree iOS manual installation docs](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/967c3b/Docs/Manual%20Integration.md), pay special attention to steps 6 and 7, namely:

- Append `/Braintree` to `Public Headers Folder Path` (e.g. `$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Headers/Braintree`) in the `Braintree` target build settings.
- Ensure you have set the [`Always Search User Paths`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW110) option to **`Yes`** in your app target's build settings. This setting tells the compiler to search the project directory for headers as well as (and before) system directories.

Also, since Xcode build configurations can be frustrating to debug, if these suggestions don't immediately resolve the issues, I highly recommend you follow the [Braintree iOS manual installation docs](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/Docs/Manual%20Integration.md) with a fresh project, and then compare settings.

Also note that we **highly** recommend using the [Braintree pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Braintree) via CocoaPods over the manual process.